# Splitting List<String> into two Lists?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

Is there a clean way of splitting a List in half and making two of them, one for the first half and the other for the second half?

The goal is to create a two column slds grid to show the list evenly in two smaller columns rather than one long column. Maybe a helper method to set the new lists or using an index during the aura:iteration?

Comment: `List<String>` is Apex, but you tagged the question JavaScript. Can you add some of your existing code and show us what you've tried to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `lightning:layout` and put your `lightning:layoutItems` inside with a size of 6. The styles will take care of laying them across two columns.

```
<lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
      {!item}
    </lightning:layoutItem>
  </aura:iteration>
</lightning:layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using lightning you can use the array.slice(start, end) to split the initial array of record in your init method.

```
var sobList = 'get your data here"
var firstHalf;
var secondhalf;
if(sobList.length > 2){
  var midIndex = parseInt(sobList.length/2); 
  firstHalf = sobList.slice(0, midIndex );
  secondhalf = sobList.slice(midIndex +1 , sobList.length -1);
}
```